# Qual é o comportamento do ciclo de vida do JSF 2 ao validar campos obrigatórios?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de clientes com dois campos, o primeiro campo é o CPF com preenchimento obrigatório e o segundo Nome com preenchimento opcional. Ao editar um cliente com CPF e Nome preenchidos, apagar os dois campos e clicar em Salvar, o JSF retorna a mensagem "O campo CPF é obrigatório". Entretanto, ao apresentar a mensagem o campo CPF vem em branco como foi submetido. O campo Nome não vem em branco como foi submetido e sim com o valor anterior.

Seria este mesmo o comportamento padrão do JSF 2? Consigo embasar este comportamento na documentação do JCP do JSF? Quais argumentos apresentar ao cliente que o campo CPF vem em branco para mostrar a obrigatoriedade e o campo Nome é restaurado porque o ciclo de vida do JSF não completou para aceitar o novo valor?

Comment: Posta sua página .xhtml e o seu managedBean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta do BalusC muito esclarecedora sobre este problema [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800/).
Ele diz:

> Quando pelo menos um componente de entrada é inválido, após a fase de validações, então não irá JSF actualizar os valores do modelo para qualquer dos componentes de entrada. JSF seguirá diretamente para renderizar fase de resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é o ciclo de vida da validação no JSF:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo de um painel de cadastro:

```
<h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="painelCadastro">
            <h:outputLabel value="CPF:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.cpf}" required="true"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="Nome:"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.nome}"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Salvar" process="painelCadastro" actionListener="#{seu_metodo_de_validar_ou_salvar}"/>
</h:form>
```

Nesse formulário a unica validação é se o campo é `required`, oque eu recomendo você fazer é um método de validação para seu objeto, onde vai validar todos os seus campos verificando se é `null` ou `empty`. O seu problema pode ser a falta de processar os novos dados para as variáveis do Bean, com o meu exemplo ele vai sempre processar os valores e vai fazer a validação do JSF.

Comment: Rafael, obrigado pela sua resposta mas o problema está em restaurar o valor sobrescrevendo o novo valor do campo nome quando o campo CPF é validado.